# How do I subtract time with a variable value in php?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a clock that allows users to select which timezone they are in which updates the clock based on timezone. The variable $timezone is whatevers selected which is an integer between -11 & 12, however I receive the error **"A non well formed numeric value encountered"**

I've tried converting the integer to a datetime but on the examples on here is subtracting two fixed DateTimes, also i've tried converting the integer to DateTime but that didn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <select id="timezone" name="timezone">
                <option name="time" value=" ">--Select Timezone--</option>
                <option name="time" value="-11">GMT-11</option>
                <option name="time" value="-10">GMT-10</option>
                <option name="time" value="-9">GMT-9</option>
                <option name="time" value="-8">GMT-8</option>
                <option name="time" value="-7">GMT-7</option>
                <option name="time" value="-6">GMT-6</option>
                <option name="time" value="-5">GMT-5</option>
                <option name="time" value="-4">GMT-4</option>
                <option name="time" value="-3">GMT-3</option>
                <option name="time" value="-2">GMT-2</option>
                <option name="time" value="-1">GMT-1</option>
                <option name="time" value="0">GMT</option>
                <option name="time" value="1">GMT+1</option>
                <option name="time" value="2">GMT+2</option>
                <option name="time" value="3">GMT+3</option>
                <option name="time" value="4">GMT+4</option>
                <option name="time" value="5">GMT+5</option>
                <option name="time" value="6">GMT+6</option>
                <option name="time" value="7">GMT+7</option>
                <option name="time" value="8">GMT+8</option>
                <option name="time" value="9">GMT+9</option>
                <option name="time" value="10">GMT+10</option>
                <option name="time" value="11">GMT+11</option>
                <option name="time" value="12">GMT+12</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>    
</html>
```

```
    <?php
      add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'displayHTMLpage' );

      function displayHTMLpage() {
          include( 'index.html' );
      }

      $dateFormat="H:i:s";
      $gmt = gmdate($dateFormat, time());

      echo $gmt;

      if(isset($_POST['timezone']))
      {
      $timezone = $_POST['timezone'];
      $time = $gmt + $timezone;
      echo $time;
      }

    ?>
```

Comment: Did you try searching the web for `A+non+well+formed+numeric+value+encountered` ?

Comment: Yes but when I use strtotime on $_POST['timezone'] when adding the value to $gmt it doesn't add up correctly. By the way the suggested answer doesn't answer my question about the time being variable.

Comment: `$gmt` is a colon-delimited string.  You are trying add an integer and a non-numeric string.  I would have thought the error message was clear enough in explaining.

Comment: How about something easy like this: https://3v4l.org/snq3M

Comment: If $gmt was an integer, when adding to $timezone it wouldn't come out as the correct time. The variable $timezone is whatever is selected (variable).

Comment: By the way this works, thanks for the link.